# How to programmatically eject locked HDD eSATA drive with PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, drive

I am trying to eject eSATA HDD drive via "USB tray icon of windows" for safe remove, but it is not possible because "another program using the drive" error (I already tired of this stup@# Windows error).

I tried this code on PowerShell:

```
$vol = get-wmiobject -Class Win32_Volume | where{$_.Name -eq 'F:\'}  
$vol.DriveLetter = $null  
$vol.Put()  
$vol.Dismount($false, $false)
```

And this other:

```
$Eject = New-Object -comObject Shell.Application
$Eject.NameSpace(17).ParseName($usbDrvLetter+“:”).InvokeVerb(“Eject”)
```

And nothing happens.

Any method valid to get this to work?

Comment: Wouldn't you have to set the dismount to `$true`?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but the overload definitions for the `.Dismount()` method are:

```
OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
System.Management.ManagementBaseObject Dismount(System.Boolean Force, System.Boolean Permanent)
```

So maybe change to: `$Vol.Dismount($true, $true)` effectively force the dismount.

I've tried testing this, except in general I think you should use the CIM cmdlets instead of *-WMI*.  `Get-WMIObject` is deprecated in Windows PowerShell and has been removed from PowerShell Core.

It's also important to consider the potential return codes ([documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/vdswmi/dismount-method-in-class-win32-volume#return-value)) from the Dismount method.

```
RETURN VALUE   Return code  Description
------------   ------------------------
0              Success
1              Access Denied
2              Volume Has Mount Points
3              Volume Does Not Support The No-Autoremount State
4              Force Option Required
```

To get the volume instance:

```
$Vol = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'E:'"
```

That's obviously similar enough to the older approach.  However, invoking methods is done a little differently:

```
$Vol | Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName Dismount -Arguments @{ Force = $true; Permanent = $true }

ReturnValue PSComputerName
----------- --------------
      2
```

And, it doesn't appear to dismount the drive.  However, if I change the arguments:

```
$Vol | Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName Dismount -Arguments @{ Force = $true; Permanent = $false }
ReturnValue PSComputerName
----------- --------------
          0
```

This does appear to dismount the drive, as Explorer shifted focus. However, the drive is still visible and when clicked can be accessed.  I never saw the Safely eject message.  It seems that Dismounting the drive is not equivalent to safely ejecting it.